# Maven test build failure

Tags: java, maven, junit

I just created a sample test case that runs fine with the `JUnit` test. I right-click on the project and choose `run as --> JUnit test`.

[image]

However, I added `maven surefire` plugin to run the same using maven. But `run as --> Maven test` fails with below error.

```
 T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.416 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-03-29T20:40:40+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-test) on project idot: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to F:\coding\github\idot\idot-backend\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: no such method: org.junit.platform.launcher.TagFilter.includeTags(List)PostDiscoveryFilter/invokeStatic
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: no such method: org.junit.platform.launcher.TagFilter.includeTags(List)PostDiscoveryFilter/invokeStatic
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:656)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:282)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:245)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1183)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1011)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:857)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

`pom.xml` junit part

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>

    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
    <junit.jupiter.version>5.4.0</junit.jupiter.version>

</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Greenwich.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Are you using JUnit, JUnit Jupiter or TestNG. ? Please add the pom file?

Comment: yes, added the same

Comment: What do you mean by, 'right-clicked' -- what ide are you using here?

Comment: adding snap, using eclipse

Comment: Remove junit-platform-launcher (you don't need it)...and go the solution in the answer....also show the full pom file...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use JUnit 5, there are a couple of thing you must be sure:

- Use latest version of Eclipse (support for JUnit 5 was added in [Oxygen 1a](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.7.1a/#junit-5-support), but you should use the latest, eg: 2020.03).
- Use at least version 2.22.2 of [maven-surefire-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) as seen in [JUnit 5 documentation here](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven-engines-configure).
- Do not specify version yourself: use the `junit-bom` in your `dependencyManagement` like you've done for `spring-cloud-dependencies`.

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
      <version>5.6.1</version>
      <scope>import</scope> <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
```

The rational is simple, and could explain your error: using the junit-bom, you are sure that dependencies your are using are compiled against the same version:

- junit.jupiter.version is 5.4.0
- junit-platform-launcher is 1.5.1

From [central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine/5.4.0), we can see that the engine is using 1.4.0 of `junit-platform-engine`: you may be introducing incompatibilities for Maven build, which may lead to the error you reported (*no such method: org.junit.platform.launcher.TagFilter.includeTags(List)PostDiscoveryFilter/invokeStatic*).

Comment: The Maven build is unrelated .it's related to the versions of JUnit Jupiter framework...

Comment: thx it worked and also solved one more error i.e. I wasn't able to run jUnit 5 test, had to run with jUnit 4

Comment: I removed the `juniper-platform-launcher` dependency, removed version from `junit-jupiter-engine` and `junit-juipter-api` and `maven-surefire-plugin`, added the `junit-bom` . `junit-bom` did the trick

Comment: @khmarbaise probably true for latest version of maven, but we don't know here. Still I've updated my answer.

Comment: The Maven version is unrelated it only depends on the version of surefire plugin and the dependencies nothing else....

Comment: I'm not a maven expert to the core, but I'd say it is for default phase/plugin binding: if you `mvn install` a fresh project with mvn 3.6.3, here is the default surefire version you get: `maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test` (and the pom I tested is as simple as it get: it only declare the GAV and nothing else). That's why I've advised to use a surefire 2.22.2/3.0.0-M4. And JUnit 5 does says it _Starting with **version 2.22.0**, Maven Surefire and Maven Failsafe provide native support for executing tests on the JUnit Platform._